# Centering Images in D3 After Transform

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, mouseevent, transform

I'm trying to move an element in D3, in order to correspond to a circle underneath. Basically, when the user zooms on the page, the circles shrink (which allows them to remain visually appealing and separated).

I want to build a function that fires with the zoom event, that keeps the images centered within the circles. The circles are centered on their center points. However, as the images shrink, they appear to move to the left because their anchors are in the top-left corner.

I need a solution that might involve adding their sacrificed width and height to their relative "x" and "y" attributes. How would I implement a function like this? Or is there a better way?

The blockbuilder is here: http://blockbuilder.org/KingOfCramers/125cc79bce7dea48b21786b37302d258

Here is the relevant bit of code (the icon variable is the starting width of the image):

```
function zoom() {
    var iconMove = icon/d3.event.transform.k;
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    d3.selectAll(".storyImages")
      .attr("width", `${iconMove}px`)
        .attr("height", `${iconMove}px`)
        .attr("x", // Keep this centered)
        .attr("y", // Keep this centered)

    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("r", function(){
         return cirSize/d3.event.transform.k
        })    
  }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can position them to start, you can update them the same way on zoom, just with the new width/height of each item. You initially append each item with these attributes:

```
.attr("x", (d) => projection([d.lat,d.lon])[0] - icon/2)
.attr("y", (d) => projection([d.lon,d.lat])[1] - icon/2)
.attr("width", `${icon}px`)
.attr("height", `${icon}px`)
```

Which offsets the icon from the x,y values returned by the projection by half the icon's width and height - centering it on the projected point. *Note: Your x value is set with d.lat, d.lon rather than d.lon, d.lat, also, your csv has lng, rather than lon as a header, so d.lng should be used).*

To keep the icon centered on the point, just update the icon using the new icon width/height (which in your case is located in `iconMove`) and the new projected point:

```
.attr("x", (d) => projection([d.lng,d.lat])[0] - iconMove/2)
.attr("y", (d) => projection([d.lng,d.lat])[1] - iconMove/2)
.attr("width", iconMove)
.attr("height", iconMove);
```

Here's an updated [block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/c1db394cca3d312703c0fe1b807f20fd) (I wasn't able to figure out how to save a new block builder block).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Having you talk through it was helpful. I kind of forgot that I could just use the initial mapping function again, except re-subtract the amount the icon moved every time. Thanks!